# To find a positive function with compact spectrum

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let 
$e_1=(0,1)^T$, 
$$
S=\left\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2\Big| \frac{|\langle x, e_1\rangle|}{|x|}>\delta>0\right\}, 
$$
is a cone in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I want to find a non-trivial smooth function which satisfies: 
$$
f\geq 0; \ \ f\equiv0 \ \mbox{on} \ S^c; \ \ \mbox{supp}\ \hat{f}\subset B_1(0). 
$$
Here $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$. I found using so called "real paley wiener theorem", which was proved in "Andersen, Nils, and Marcel de Jeu.  Real Paley-Wiener theorems and local spectral radius formulas.  Transactions of the American Mathematical Society 362.7 (2010): 3613-3640," the last condition can be rewrote as:
$$
|\nabla^k f(x)|\leq Ck^N(1+|x|)^N. 
$$

Thanks a lot if one can give me any comment or reference.

Comment: What is $\hat f$? Fourier transform of $f$? If so, such a function does not exist. If the Fourier transform has compact support, the function is analytic, so it cannot vanish on the complement of $S$ unless it is identically zero.

Comment: Yes, $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform of $f$. You mean a real analytic function cannot vanish on an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: @JohnZhao: [yes, as explained here](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Real_analytic_function#Analytic_varieties_and_unique_continuation)

Comment: @MichaelRenardy, Oh, I see. My question is really trivial! Thank you so much for your help.